# How do I check email in backend register

Tags: javascript, node.js, backend

I have a problem with my code now and I can't make it work. I am trying to check if the email added by the user is already in the database so I can generate an error message to the person and I don't know exactly how to check this. Can someone please help me?  Thank you so much

Backend code now:

```
//Create user
app.post("/register/users", (req, res, next) => {
  let userData = {
    name: req.body.name,
    email: req.body.email,
    password: req.body.password,
  };
  const user = new User(userData);
  user
    .save()
    .then((result) => {
      res.status(200).json(result._id);
    })
    .catch((error) => res.status(422).json(error));
  // console.log(res.body);
});
```

How can I check if user with similar email is already register to display the error? Thank you so much for your time

Comment: Can you search for the email in your data store before data insertion??

Answer (score 0):

You can do a check before saving the user.

First, check if the user with the same email exists in the database.
If exist, do not save again, instead send the response.
If not exist, save the user.

```js
app.post("/register/users", async (req, res, next) => {
  let userData = {
    name: req.body.name,
    email: req.body.email,
    password: req.body.password,
  };
  // checkin if a user with the mail exist
  try {
    const existingUser = await User.findOne({ email: req.body.email });
    if (existingUser) {
      // you may want to send different status code
      return res.status(200).json({ message: 'User alreay registered });
    }
    const user = new User(userData);
    // save the user
    const newUser = await user.save();
    return res.status(200).json(newUser._id);
  } catch(error) {
    return res.status(422).json({ error });
});
```

Comment: Hi @Shams Nahid, thanks for your response. I tried the code and it always sends back that the email is registered and also it's not saving the new user in the database. Do you have any idea why? Thanks

Comment: You may consider to put a debugger to check what inside the `existingUser` object or do a console of the `existingUser`. Ideally, the `existingUser` should be empty when the email is new.

Comment: Please try the updated code. Insted of getting an array in existingUser, now it will return object.